# Condition if elseif

Tags: php

I have a problem with a condition.
What I want to do is :

For each ages I check in my db, echo only one thing :

If all ages are == 0, echo "ok".

If one or more ages == 1, echo "almost ok".

If one or more ages == 2, echo "not ok".

```
   foreach($results as $row){
         if($row['age'] == 0){
               echo "ok";
         }
         else if ($row['age'] == 1){
               echo "almost ok";
         }              
         else if($row['age'] == 2){
               echo "not ok";
         }
    }
```

I did this, but it will echo for every row. Any help will be appreciated!!

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try elseif?

Comment: Give your foreach loop a [`break;`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Comment: Can you explain the connection between `age` and `ages`here and what it mean when you say `all ages` & `one or more` , because currently you are checking each `age` and print some thing if this one/single `age`  is `0,1,2`!?

Comment: Display `print_r($results);`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly; Okay. Thanks.

Comment: You are processing, I assume, more than one result row. So add some other info to your echo like `name` and you will see you are getting more than one answer because you are testing more than one result row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do something like this (assuming the array contains only 0,1,2) :

```
$containsOne = false;
$containstwo = false;

// first loop over all results to check the content of the array
foreach($results as $row){
     if ($row['age'] == 1){
          $containsOne = true;
     }              
     if($row['age'] == 2){
          $containsTwo = true;
     }
}

// once the loop is done, check the results and echo the correct message
if (!$containsOne && ! $containsTwo) echo 'OK';
if ($containsOne  && ! $containsTwo) echo 'Almost OK';
if ($containsTwo) echo 'Not OK';
```

Comment: Actually, @Rizier123's suggestion of simply adding a `break` should do the trick (according to the question) and be faster, too, no?

Comment: no because if the 1st element is a `1` and the last is a `2`, it should print `not OK`, with a break it will print `almost OK`

Comment: @domdom, `break` wont help if the array  - `[0,0,0,1,2,0]`

Comment: Ah, very true. Ignore me then. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. Indeed, with the break; it doesn't work.

Comment: @xarj  you need to do break if the second condition occurred ("not ok" case), there is no need to continue the loop, also there is no need to check the both flags, this will low the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can store variables count and check these after the loop:

```
$numAge0 = $numAge1 = $numAge2 = 0;
foreach($results as $row)
{
    if($row['age'] == 0) $numAge0++;
    if($row['age'] == 1) $numAge1++;
    if($row['age'] == 2) $numAge2++;
}

if($numAge2) echo "not ok";
elseif($numAge1) echo "almost ok";
else echo "ok";
```

Comment: @xarj You are welcome, please flag my answer as accepted :)

Comment: can only flag one answer, sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declare 3 counters. Say counterZero, CounterOne & CounterTwo
    foreach($results as $row){
             if($row['age'] == 0){
                   //counterZero++; Increment counterZero
             }
             else if ($row['age'] == 1){
             //counterOne++; Increment counterOne
             }              
             else if($row['age'] == 2){
                  //counterTwo++; Increment counterOne
             }
         }
         //Now Check 
         if(counterZero>0 && CounterOne==0 && CounterTwo==0)
            echo "OK";
         else if (counterOne>0)
            echo "AlmostOk";
         else if (counterTwo>0)
echo "not ok";
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do the "evaluation part" with if outside your foreach loop, e.g. like this:

```
$ageStatus = 0;
foreach ($results as $row) {
    if ($row['age'] == 1) {
        $ageStatus = 1;
    };
    if ($row['age'] == 2) {
        $ageStatus = 2;
    };
}

if ($ageSum == 0 ) {
    echo "ok";
}
if ($ageSum == 1 ) {
    echo "almost ok";
}
if ($ageSum == 2 ) {
    echo "not ok";
}
```

You're getting bonus points converting that into a switch statement ;)

Comment: and how do you differenciate [0,0,1,1] and [0,0,0,2] ? the sum will be the same but the message must be different

Comment: You're right, summing up doesn't solve the problem. There has to be a status, and in case age is 1, switch to "almost ok", in case there is a 2, switch to "not ok". After the foreach, you're evaluating the status and print the text. After the foreach, not inside. This way, the will only be 1 echo.

Answer (score -2):

you need to check all the rows before printing anything, so you sould use flags as follow:

```
$almost_ok = false;
$not_ok = false;

foreach($results as $row){
    if ($row['age'] == 1){
       $almost_ok = true;
    }              
    else if($row['age'] == 2){
       $not_ok = true;
       break;
    }
}

if($not_ok)
    echo "not ok";
elseif($almost_ok)
    echo "almost ok";
else
    echo "ok";
```

Comment: `break` will not help.

Comment: @SougataBose a break at the second case is needed, so if its 'not ok' there is no need to continue the loop

Comment: For that second condition it is okay